# Simple odometry with kinect

Tags: navigation, odometry, kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello community,

is it possible to generate any simple odometry informations from kinect sensor ?

Thanks in advance
Cheers
Christian

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12155/simple-odometry-with-kinect/) by [Chrimo](https://answers.ros.org/users/361/chrimo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 390 on 2011-11-30

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Generating odometry information from a camera or depth-sensor like a Kinect is an incredibly difficult problem. [Vslam](http://www.ros.org/wiki/vslam) is an attempt to generate visual odometry data from a stereo-camera setup. The Kinect can provide you with the same information as a stereo camera system, in that it publishes an image and a depth map. I believe there have been attempts to use vslam with the Kinect before, but I'm not sure what kind of reliability people have been getting.

Building a 3D obstacle map using SLAM and gmapping can easily be done with the Kinect, however.  You can find an example [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_navigation/Tutorials/Build%20a%20map%20with%20SLAM).

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2011-11-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tom](https://answers.ros.org/users/58/tom/) on 2011-11-30**:
see here: http://answers.ros.org/question/502/how-to-use-canonical_scan_matcher-with-kinect

**Comment by [tom](https://answers.ros.org/users/58/tom/) on 2011-11-30**:
Building a 3D obstacle map using SLAM and gmapping can be easily done with Kinect instead of a laser scanner, but not without an odometry source. The question was to obtain odometry from laser. I've tried that with Kinect, kinect_to_laser, and laser_scan_matcher. But the results were rather bad

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes you can generate odometry estimates from a Kinect, although I wouldn't call it a "simple" process.

There will always be issues with Visual Odometry when there aren't great features, and there are various feature descriptors to choose from that perform differently.

Check [rgbdslam](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rgbdslam) for an example of applied visual odom.

---

Originally posted by [phil0stine](https://answers.ros.org/users/639/phil0stine/) with karma: 682 on 2011-11-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's definitely technically complex. But if you're just looking for an implementation, there is a CCNY's experimental stack in which there is a package called *`kinect_pose_est`*. Works as presented [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kXJ0mq0hA18). There is a paper to it, see: http://robotics.ccny.cuny.edu/blog/People/Dryanovski , guess it's the number 1 paper. Hope it helps.

Clone the package via:

```
git clone http://robotics.ccny.cuny.edu/git/ccny-ros-pkg/ccny_experimental.git
```

Also see this question: http://answers.ros.org/question/502/how-to-use-canonical_scan_matcher-with-kinect

Regards.

---

Originally posted by [tom](https://answers.ros.org/users/58/tom/) with karma: 1079 on 2011-11-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1